# Are Vinyl Questions on Topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are general vinyl questions on topic here, or should they be asked in Music Fans SE?  They wouldn't really relate to the practice or theory of music, but not necessarily for fans of music....  Music Fans does contain a tag for vinyl (which music.SE does not.) Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

They are more on topic on the music fan SE then here as the most common questions  for vinyl records are collecting, listening,  and care which is more along the line of Music Fan SE then here.

The only questions that would be more appropriate here are related to using vinyl in a performance as is common for a DJ.

Comment: What if it's about mastering and/or pressing of vinyl?

Comment: I can't see mastering and pressing being on topic here at all. There may be elements on topic at music fans, and some on topic at sound design

Comment: And what about using vinyl in DJ performance? (Note: answering "no" might create a precedent that would make *all* DJ stuff off-topic, which, the snobby elitist I am, would please me greatly :) )

Comment: @SomeDudeOnTheInterwebs: [Already handled](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/709/are-djs-unwelcome-on-musical-practice-performance)

Comment: @JacobSwanson: For mastering/pressing there's a proposed [Music Production SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82083/music-production), which would fit the bill. Hoping to see that one take off, as we don't have enough expertise to handle that area currently. (Edit: Saw now that you were aware of it, leaving the comment since it might get some more people to discover it...)